# Не работает плавная анимация смены значение left css на safari

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

У меня есть меню с значение left: -100%, при нажатии на кнопку меню я задаю ему значение left: 0, при этому у блока есть transition: .4s. При тестировании с пк мобильной версии, анимация плавная и все работает. Но на iphone этой анимации нет

Comment: Приложите код, чтоб потестировать.

Comment: попробуйте добавить префикс для свойства